# Message written to a channel not going into the pipeline

Tags: java, networking, netty

So this is happening with both the server and client. I have the ChannelHandlerContext from the channelActive method and I am trying to write an object to it using the writeAndFlush(Object msg) method, but it seems the msg never goes into the pipeline created.

Here is what my client handler looks like (I overrided some methods in the packet decoder and encoder to debug)

```
public ChannelHandlerContext channel;
...
...
(method to start client is called)


EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(workerGroup);
            b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(
                            new PacketDecoder(clientRegistries){
                                @Override
                                protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
                                    List<Packet> packets = PacketHelper.handle(in, ctx, super.serverRegistries);
                                    packets.forEach(packet -> {
                                        System.out.println(packet.getClass());
                                    });
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                                    channel = ctx;
                                    ctx.fireChannelActive();
                                }
                            },
                            new PacketEncoder(){
                                @Override
                                protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Pair<PacketRegistry, Packet> msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
                                    System.out.println("message encoded on client sent to server");
                                    super.encode(ctx, msg, out);
                                }
                            }
                    );

                }
            });

ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host, port).sync();
```

Here is how I write to the ChannelHandlerContext channel variable

```
    public void sendPacket(PacketRegistry registry, Packet p) {
        System.out.println("data written to server from client");
        channel.writeAndFlush(new Pair<>(registry, p));
    }
```

When I run my code, "data written to server from client" is printer, but "message encoded on client sent to server" is never printed.

I am wondering what I did wrong, any help would be appreciated. And like stated above, the same thing happens on the server when I try to write using the ChannelHandlerContext from the channelActive method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer and its pretty simple.
Instead of using the channelActive method (which is for udp), I needed to use the channelRegistered method (which is for tcp).

Comment: Thats not true... `channelActive(...)` is called for TCP as well as soon as the connection is established.

Comment: Yes I find this to be true as well. The channelActive is called. Otherwise I would have gotten a null pointer exception on the client